# $\{\frac1n, n\in \mathbb{N}^*\}$ is localy connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I have this set $A=\{\frac1n, n\in \mathbb{N}^*\}$

How can I prove that this set is locally connected but $\overline{A}$ is not locally connected.

Thank you

Comment: Which is the topology on A?

Comment: they don't say what is the topology

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

Notice that every point in $A$ is a connected neighborhood of itself, because $\{\frac{1}{n}\}=A \cap (\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n-1})$.

To show that $\bar{A}$ is not locally connected, consider any neighborhood $U$ (in $\bar{A}$) of the point $0$, which has the form $A \cap (-\epsilon, \epsilon)$, for some $\epsilon >0$. Choose $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$. Choose any point $p$ such that $\frac{1}{n+1} < p < \frac{1}{n}$. Then $p \notin  U$, since $U \subset A$, so $U \cap (-\epsilon,p)$ and $U \cap (p, \epsilon)$ form a separation of $U$. Thus $U$ is not connected.

Comment: How to find the neighborhoods i don't have the topology

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's assumed to be the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: then a neighborhood of x is $]x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon[\cap A$ ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: Sorry, my previous answer was a bit misleading. So I edited it.

Comment: please i still don't understand why 0 has no connected neighborhood, please explaine me again

Comment: Okay, I made my answer more detailed.

Comment: A neighborhood of $0\in \overline{A}$ is of the form $]-\varepsilon,\varepsilon[\cap \overline{A}$ no ?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wrote. I just use the notation $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ instead of $]-\epsilon,\epsilon[$. They mean the same thing, though.